# Output from function in another one

Tags: c++

In my C++ project, I have 3 files which are main.cpp, functions.cpp and functions.h.

functions.cpp:

```
#include <functions.h>

using namespace std;

int ascii(string text)
{
    vector<int> tab;

    for( int i=0; i<text.length(); i++ )
    {
        char x = text.at(i);
        tab.push_back(x);
    }

    for(int k=0; k<tab.size(); k++)
    {
        cout << tab[k] << endl;
    }
}
```

functions.h:

```
#ifndef FUNCTIONS_H_INCLUDED
#define FUNCTIONS_H_INCLUDED

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int ascii(std::string text);

#endif // FUNCTIONS_H_INCLUDED
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <functions.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string plaintext;
    cout << "Enter text : ";
    ws(cin);
    getline(cin, plaintext);

    ascii(plaintext);

    return 0;
}
```

As you can see, the value are stored in an array in the functions.cpp file.

How do I "move" the array from functions.cpp to main.cpp so I can manipulate these data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to do following

functions.cpp

```
using namespace std;

vector<int> ascii(string text) // original: int ascii(string text)
{
    vector<int> tab;

    for( int i=0; i<text.length(); i++ )
    {
        char x = text.at(i);
        tab.push_back(x);
    }

    for(int k=0; k<tab.size(); k++)
    {
        cout << tab[k] << endl;
    }

    return tab;  // original: no return
}
```

functions.h

```
#ifndef FUNCTIONS_H_INCLUDED
#define FUNCTIONS_H_INCLUDED

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

std::vector<int> ascii(std::string text); // original int ascii(std::string text)

#endif // FUNCTIONS_H_INCLUDED
```

main.cpp

```
#include <functions.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string plaintext;
    cout << "Enter text : ";
    ws(cin);
    getline(cin, plaintext);

    vector<int> returning = ascii(plaintext); // original: ascii(plaintext)

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I tried to do like that but the problem is this one :
`main.cpp:12:44: error: conversion from ‘int’ to non-scalar type ‘std::vector<int>’ requested
`

Comment: instead of `int ascii(string text)` you have to put `vector<int> ascii(string text)` I just tried it and it works.

Comment: Same error : `main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:12:44: error: conversion from ‘int’ to non-scalar type ‘std::vector<int>’ requested
`

Comment: sorry forgot that you need to change functions.h

Comment: sorry :( it should of been different :) `vector<int> ascii()`

Comment: Thanks ! You made my whole day :D